# Style in SVG, not applied on the browser (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styling

I'm trying to add a SVG into my webpage, I think the format is a bit odd.

https://gist.github.com/Vadorequest/c329dec26e39a586e96df5f74c1d7d29?short_path=d29c6c9 (you can see the source code and the rendering there)

The `style` part isn't correctly understood since I'm loading this file using React. If you save the file and open it in a browser, it'll work fine. But if I load it by react using `react-svg-loader`, it displays a dark image.

```
import IconBook from "-!react-svg-loader!../assets/couverture-eBook-VF.svg";
...
<IconBook height={250} />
```

Is it standard to put the style like this? Should I get a new SVG exported differently? I really don't know that format and all its possibilities.

---

Edit 1:

I found a working workaround for anyone interested: https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-inlinesvg

It basically loads the svg file over network and anything in it will be correctly loaded. (including `<styles>`)

On the bad side, it makes the app rely on something that must be available via CDN or alike. (you won't have the svg embedded in your app. If you wanted some kind of standalone app that can be built with everything in it, it's not really good)

On the good side, it doesn't require any change in the SVG file, you use it as it, load it over network, and it displays as in the browser.

Since I'm building a standalone app (basically, `npm run build` will generate a folder with my whole app) this isn't perfect because I need to host that file somewhere on a CDN. So I'll keep looking for another solution.

Comment: why bother with the loader? you can just make a regular component, then pass whatever props you want

Comment: How do you build you react app?

Comment: I'm using create-react-app. But I don't wanna have to make a dedicated component for all icons... Must be a pain to do and to maintain! :/

Comment: how does React seem to load the SVG into the page?   I ask, since I have been doing a lot of SVG in web pages of late, and there are lots of quirks when using SVG.  It should take the CSS from the whole HTML document or the CSS in your SVG.   I would suggest two things.  1) try and ensure that your namespaces are defined (and correctly) by React, and see if you don't have any overriding CSS.  I'm sure you've tried everything and so the second is probably obvious, but it's always misspelt words that always gets me.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to have styles in your svg file, as specification says:

> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a stylesheet language used to describe
>   the presentation of a document written in HTML or XML (including XML
>   dialects such as SVG or XHTML). CSS describes how elements should be
>   rendered on screen, on paper, in speech, or on other media.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's actually supported. Can you add a link to the spec? Thanks :)

Comment: Updated answer with link